Next.js 14 all pages built as dynamic
Summary
I have layout.tsx
 <body>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <NotistackProvider maxSnack={3}>
            <SessionProvider>
              <Stack>
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
              </Stack>
            </SessionProvider>
          </NotistackProvider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>

when I build the app, static & dynamic pages created as expected;
However, I need to add a <Header/> server component with sign-in & sing-out logic. Layout.tsx become
<body>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <NotistackProvider maxSnack={3}>
            <SessionProvider>
              <Stack>
                <Header />
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
              </Stack>
            </SessionProvider>
          </NotistackProvider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>

Altough the application runs OK, all the pages become dynamic unnecessarily;
How to keep the <Header/> and still separate static & dynamic pages correctly?
Header.tsx is like this;
async function Header() {
  const session = await auth();

  const title = "Assessment System";

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, height: "64px" }}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <HeaderTitle title={title} />

          {!!session && (
            <>
              <Chip
                variant="filled"
                color="info"
                label={
                  <>
                    <Typography
                      variant="subtitle2"
                      component="div"
                      sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    >
                      {session?.user.name}
                    </Typography>
                  </>
                }
              ></Chip>
            </>
          )}
          {!session && <SignIn />}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Header;


